# manually trigger lazy load for images iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, lazy-loading

so I have an iframe where the images in the iframe are set to lazy load but the lazy load won’t trigger on small screens or some browsers.

```
<iframe src='https://opensea.io/collection/sorare?embed=true'
        width='100%'
        height='2500'
        frameborder='0'
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

is there a way to trigger the lazy load within the iframe on page load. maybe

```
("img.lazyload").trigger("appear");
```

or

```
lazyLoadInstance.update()
```

[How to interact with the content of an iframe using js or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029790/how-to-interact-with-the-content-of-an-iframe-using-js-or-jquery)

Comment: On which screen/browser are you facing this problem?

Comment: @PrateekGoyal on iphone 8 and iphone SE safari and brave browser. also on desktop safari if i shrink the window to a certain width.