# Interactions from within an iframe in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, embed

I have a multiuser environment where if any user makes any change to the page I broadcast it to the other users. Recently I have integrated iframe for embedding third-party websites. How can I detect changes from inside an iframe so that I can broadcast that in the same fashion?

For example, let's say I have an embedded iframe of Google Maps. If one user pans the map I want this action to be broadcasted to other users as well so that all the user sees the same thing. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029790/how-to-interact-with-the-content-of-an-iframe-using-js-or-jquery) might help? You probably can't interact with a Google Maps iFrame since it's not in the same domain scope as your page.

Comment: @filipe I have found lots of these comments and issues previously created. However, they all work if and only if the domain is the same. I would like to do it for any third-party website that enables us to embed their iframe on our website, e.g. Google Maps, Youtube, Slideshare, etc. I'd like to know if there is any way to achieve this.

Comment: You can't, and that's on purpose. Otherwise anyone could embed any website and run arbitrary code, i.e. build the easiest phishing attempts ever seen. This can't be done and that's A Very Good Thing.